# Ошибка сегментирования. malloc внутри функции

Tags: c, функции, segmentation-fault

```
//file_test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 100

typedef struct book {
   char *title;
   char *first_name;
   char *second_name;
   int allPages;
   int lastPage;
} Book;

void getTitle(char *t, FILE *fp);
int getLastPage(FILE *fp);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Book bookShelf[SIZE];
    Book tBook;
    char temp[SIZE];

FILE *file_pointer = fopen("readthis.txt", "a+");
if(!file_pointer) {
    printf("Can not open this file.\n");
    return 1;
} else printf("File succesfully opened.\n");

if(argc == 2) {
    getTitle(tBook.title, file_pointer);
    printf("in 32\n");
    printf("title = %s\n", tBook.title);
    if(strcmp(tBook.title,argv[1]) == 0)
        printf("in 34\n");
        tBook.lastPage = getLastPage(file_pointer);
        printf("Last page was %d\n", tBook.lastPage);
}

    printf("--end--\n");
    return 0;
}

#define ARSZ 1000

void getTitle(char *t, FILE *fp) {
    t = NULL;
    printf("in begining of getTitle\n");
    char temp[ARSZ];
    int c,i;
    for(i = 0;(c = getc(fp)) != ';';i++)
        temp[i] = c;
    temp[i] = '\0';
    t = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(temp) + 1));
    if(t == NULL) printf("t == NULL\n");
    printf("in 56: %s\n", t);
strcpy(t, temp);
printf("at the end of getTitle\n");
printf("in 59: %s\n", t);
}

int getLastPage(FILE *fp) {
    char temp[ARSZ];
    int c, i;
    for (i = 0; i < ARSZ && (c = getc(fp)) != ';'; ++i)
        temp[i] = c;
    return atoi(temp);
}
```

Результат работы:

```
./file_test.out 2

File succesfully opened.
in begining of getTitle
in 56:
at the end of getTitle
in 59: Сила привычки
in 32
title = (null)
Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти)
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь отладчиком, "пошагайте" вашу программу. Это не сложно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Она у вас работать и не должна. Но `malloc` здесь в полной мере ни при чем. Здесь у вас - неверная передача параметра в функцию. Не хотите пока остановиться и попробовать по этой подсказке самостоятельно понять, где и почему?

Если нет - ну, давайте рассмотрим вызов

```
getTitle(tBook.title, file_pointer);
```

Как, по-вашему, что она делает?
У вас есть локальная неинициализированная переменная `tBook`, заполненная мусором. Этот мусор в поле `title` вы передаете в `getTitle`. Что она делает? Присваивает своей **локальной** переменной-параметру `t`, в которой содержался мусор, значение `NULL`, потом читает строку, выделяет память, копирует... Потом при выходе благополучно забывает об этой выделенной памяти (поздравляю с утечкой), так что по завершении вызова имеем прочитанное в потерянное место строку из файла и тот же мусор в `tBook.title`.

Видимо, под отладчиком, или случайно этот мусор у вас оказывается нулем.

О чем вам и сообщается в строке

```
printf("title = %s\n", tBook.title);
```

На всякий случай намекаю - если вы хотите изменять передаваемую в фцнкцию переменную - передавайте ее не по значению, а по адресу.